# Import a custom csv with associations for a model in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import, activeadmin

I'm using Rails 4.2

In ActiveAdmin I want to upload a CSV with two fields - a product's barcode (unique for each product) and the price of it.
I have three tables:

- **retailers** [id, name] - represented as **Retailer** by ActiveRecord
- **products** [id, barcode (unique), name] - represented as **Product** by ActiveRecord
- **retailer_has_products** [id, retailer_id, product_id, price] - represented as **RetailerHasProduct** by ActiveRecord

**RetailerHasProduct** is a representation of an intermediate table for many to many relation on **products** with **retailers**.

The *barcode* is a reference for a **product**. I want to find the related **product**, take it's *id* field value and insert it with the *price* into **retailer_has_products**.

The problem starts with the *retailer_id*. How I want to get it? From the "show" page of a specific retailer in ActiveAdmin.

Is it possible to upload the CSV with associations to a specific record of the Retailer model within ActiveAdmin?

Cheers!

Comment: Did you found an answer? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Am having the same problem as well, any solution?

Comment: @chrisgeeq No, sorry - couldn't find any solution to that and I left the project years ago :(

Comment: @OfirSasson unfortunately no and I left the project years ago :(

Comment: I found a way around that, i will post my solution later